# How to encrypt a String using GnuPG class?

Tags: java, encryption, pgp, gnupg

```
   try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gpg --armor --batch --encrypt -r "+ rcpt);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("Error creating process.");
  }
```

I'm trying to encrypt a String text. This is an excerpt from the class that does the encryption. 'rcpt' is my keyID for encryption. I keep getting a **null pointer exception**. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I will be very glad to receive your help.

Comment: If you're running into NullPointerExceptions, please post the full exception with stack trace and use the debugger to realize which field exactly is null. These are information that are necessary to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(("gpg --armor --batch --encrypt -r "+ rcpt)
                    .split("\\s+"));
```